# Gettin error 'Because flutter_app depends on flutterfire any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed. ' after flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

Gettin this error after updating flutter

`Shabbir@Shabbirs-MacBook-Pro flutter_app % flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (3.5s)
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.3.

Because flutter_app depends on flutterfire any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see [https://dart.dev/null-safety`](https://dart.dev/null-safety%60)

pubspec.yaml

`name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutterfire:

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase_core: ^2.10.0
firebase_auth: ^4.4.2
cloud_firestore: ^4.5.3
firebase_analytics: ^10.2.1

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

uses-material-design: true`

Tried updating oubspec.yaml but still no success